# How to get the types of a method's parameters on a derived class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-component, custom-element

I want to create a class that mixes in [custom HTML elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements) with some additional properties and methods: if I extend the class to create a new component, the new component will be a custom HTML element with the additional properties/methods.

One functionality I'm trying to add is a helper to define and dispatch custom events. Ideally each component will have an `events` object that defines each event, including:

1. The event name
2. The "shape" of the data passed with the event
3. Any transformations that should happen on the data passed with the event

Then when some interaction occurs we can `emit` the event and dispatch it with the proper data.

For example, let's say we're creating a storefront where people can buy bakery items:

```
export function ComponentFactory(BaseHTMLElement: typeof HTMLElement) {
    return class Component extends BaseHTMLElement {
        events = {} as Record<string, (...args: Array<any>) => any>; // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any

        emit<
            EventKey extends keyof this[`events`],
            EventDetail extends this[`events`][EventKey],
        >(eventKey: EventKey, ...args: Parameters<EventDetail>) {
            const eventName = eventKey as string;
            const getDetail = this.events[eventName] as EventDetail;
            const detail = getDetail(...args) as ReturnType<EventDetail>;
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(eventName, {
                bubbles: true,
                detail,
            }));
        }
    };
}

export class BakeryItem extends ComponentFactory(HTMLDivElement) {
    events = {
        buy: (quantity: number) => quantity,
        buyDozen: (dozens: number) => dozens * 12,
    };

    onBuyClick(quantity: number) {
        this.emit(`buy`, quantity);
    }

    onBuyDozenClick(quantity: number) {
        this.emit(`buyDozen`, quantity);
    }
}
```

Typescript throws errors when calling `this.emit`. For example, when calling `this.emit('buy', quantity)`:

> `Argument of type '[number]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Parameters<this["events"]["buy"]>'.`

However when I call `new BakeryItem().emit('buy', 3)` it correctly infers all the types and does not throw errors.

How can I correctly type this so that I can call both `bakeryItem.emit` and `new BakeryItem().emit`?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get this to work by having ComponentFactory accept a generic as the type of your `events` object and then using that to construct your generic types within the emit function. When I was doing initial testing here it seems like the `Parameters` generic really dislikes values from pure array access (e.g. `Parameters<(typeof this)["events"]["buy"]>` instead of `Parameters<typeof this.events.buy>`). Below is how I managed to get this to work, but it does require adding a parameter to do the type inference to your `ComponentFactory` function:

```js
export function ComponentFactory<
  T extends Record<string, (...args: any[]) => any>
>(BaseHTMLElement: typeof HTMLElement, events: T) {
  return class Component extends BaseHTMLElement {
    events = events;

    emit<EventKey extends keyof T, EventDetail extends T[EventKey]>(
      eventKey: EventKey,
      ...args: Parameters<T[EventKey]>
    ) {
      const eventName = eventKey as string;
      const getDetail = this.events[eventName] as EventDetail;
      const detail = getDetail(...args) as ReturnType<EventDetail>;
      this.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent(eventName, {
          bubbles: true,
          detail,
        })
      );
    }
  };
}

export class BakeryItem extends ComponentFactory(HTMLDivElement, {
  buy: (quantity: number) => quantity,
  buyDozen: (dozens: number) => dozens * 12,
}) {
  onBuyClick(quantity: number) {
    this.emit("buy", quantity);
  }

  onBuyDozenClick(quantity: number) {
    this.emit("buyDozen", quantity);
  }
}
```

(kudos to my situationship who saw this and immediately suggested it)

Comment: Thanks! I'm hoping to avoid passing in the events as a parameter because I want to be able to easily access `this` within the event functions, but it's very validating to know that you're running into the same issues. :) I've had a _ton_ of trouble over the years with `Parameters` thinking something is/isn't an array. In this case it turns out the function works fine if the event functions accept a single parameter instead of multiple, so I'm just going to do that.

Comment: Ah, yes, I did seem to get it to work using Parameters<>[0] (it's usually what I default to while using the Parameters generic), but it was definitely puzzling why it wouldn't accept an answer that pulls from the generated tuple type. Technically I suppose you could support some arbitrary number of parameters by discretely listing Parameters[0], Parameters[1], etc as separate args but that can definitely become cumbersome I can imagine